# BiometricPromptCompat is missing

Tags: android, biometrics

Android P introduced changes to the `Biometrics API`.
Now we should use `BiometricPrompt` class to integrate biometric authentication in our apps (`FingerprintManager` is deprecated).

The issue is that this class is only available on API 28.

[Biometrics documentation](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/06/better-biometrics-in-android-p.html) says:

> A support library is also provided for devices running Android O and earlier, allowing applications to utilize the advantages of this API across more devices .

But I can't find that support library.
Does it exist? Or will be added in future implementations?

Comment: Don't know if you found it already, but `1.0.0-alpha01` was released in September. Latest version is `1.0.0-alpha02`. Add this to your build.gradle: 
`implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-alpha02'`. 
([Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.biometric/biometric))

Comment: @JayShortway Thanks! Add it as an answer please, so I can accept it

Comment: Happy to help :) I just added it as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think at the time of your question, it *was* missing. `1.0.0-alpha01` was released in September. Latest version as of now is `1.0.0-alpha02`.
Add this to your build.gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-alpha02'
```

([Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.biometric/biometric))

Comment: when i add this in my build.gradle file , i always have an error : Could not find method implementation() for arguments [androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-alpha03] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler. I have gradle version 4.10. But i am using Cordova android ( version 5.1.0) ... I am fed up with the issue .. please help

Comment: @Rakesh Which version of Android Studio are you using? You could try replacing 'implementation' with 'compile' to see if it works, but 'compile' is actually deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

As @JayShortway answered the backwards-compatible dependency is:

```
implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-alpha02'
```

But the implementation is different from the `android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricPrompt` implementation:

```
class BiometricsManagerImpl {

    private val executor = MainThreadExecutor()

    override fun authenticate(activity: FragmentActivity) {
        val prompt = BiometricPrompt(
            activity,
            executor,
            object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {                        
                    super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
                    // Handle authentication errors
                }

                override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                    super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
                    // Authentication Succeeded
                }
            })

        val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("Biometric Authentication")
            .setDescription("Please authenticate in order to verify your identity")
            .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
            .build()

        prompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
    }

    inner class MainThreadExecutor : Executor {
        private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

        override fun execute(runnable: Runnable) {
            handler.post(runnable)
        }
    }
}
```